# having issues displaying objects from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having an issue with getting the data from my state I need the information from the employee state to display the pages in referring to are Employee.js and EmployeeItem.js in my repo.
I can map through the state and display a number of blank objects based on how many entries are in the state but I am having trouble displaying and information for the individual objects

How the page currently renders
[image: How the page currently renders]

How I need the page to render
[image: How I need the page to render]

Employee.js

```
import React, {Fragment, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import Spinner from '../../layout/Spinner'
import {getEmployees} from '../../../actions/employee'
import EmployeeItem from './EmployeeItem'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Employees = ({ getEmployees, employee: {employees, loading}}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getEmployees()
    }, [])

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {loading ? <Spinner/> :
                <Fragment>
                    <section className="content bg-light">
                            <h1 className="x-large text-primary title">Employees</h1>
                            <div className="add">
                                <Link to="/employees/new"><i className="fas fa-plus-circle text-primary x-large"></i></Link>
                            </div>
                                {employees.length > 0 ? (
                                    employees.map(employee => (
                                        <EmployeeItem key={employee._id} profile={employee} />
                                    ))
                                ) : <h4>No Employees Found....</h4>}
                    </section>
                </Fragment>
            }
        </Fragment>
    )
}

Employees.propTypes = {
    getEmployees: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    employee: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    employee: state.employee
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getEmployees})(Employees)
```

EmployeeItem.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const EmployeeItem = ({employee: name, employement, _id}) => {
    return (
        <div className="employee-container">
            <Link to={`/employees/${_id}`}>
                <div className="employee-icon bg-white">
                    <div className="circle-sal">
                        <h4 className="large initials">J D</h4>
                    </div>
                    <p className="lead-2">{name}</p>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

EmployeeItem.propTypes = {
    employee: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default EmployeeItem
```

[What is in the state:
[image: What is in the state]

Any help on fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Evaluating from your picture, the name is not being displayed. Am I correct?

Comment: you are directly de-structuring your props to employee. which will be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the EmployeeItem. You are assigning employee value to profile prop.

```
<EmployeeItem key={employee._id} profile={employee} />
```

and you are trying to access the value wrongly.

```
const EmployeeItem = ({employee: name, employement, _id}) => {
}
```

You could have done either this way

```
<EmployeeItem key={employee._id} profile={employee} />
```

and  in EmployeeItem

```
const EmployeeItem = ({ profile: { name, _id } }) => {
}
```

**or**

```
<EmployeeItem key={employee._id} {...employee} />
```

and  in EmployeeItem

```
const EmployeeItem = ({ name, _id }) => {
}
```